# how to call method without knowing the class name?

Tags: java, class, field, overloading, anonymous

I have defined two classes below:

```
public class junk {
   private BigInteger a = BigIngeger.valueOf(1), b=BigInteger.valueOf(2), c;

   public void DoSomething() {
      c = a.add(b);
   }

   // ... other stuff here
}

public class junkChild extends junk {
   private BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(1), b=BigDecimal.valueOf(2), c;
   // I want a, b, c to override the original BigInteger a,b,c 
   // ... other stuff here
}     

public class myClass {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      junk a1 = new junkChild();
      a1.DoSomething();
   }
}
```

Unfortunately the above does not work.

What I want to do is to simply change `a`, `b`, `c` to `BigDecimal` in `junkChild` without rewriting `DoSomething()` again. Even if I have to write it again, the code will be exactly the same, so there should be a way I can make this work without having to write it. The `DoSomething` function should check that the type `a1` has an `add` method of the correct input and return type, and if so, invoke it without being worried about what type `a`, `b`, `c` are.

Can this be done?

Comment: You should read up on reflection. It will fulfil the second part of your question. As for the first part, don't use fields `a`, `b`, and `c` directly, but instead use methods `getA`, `getB`, and `getC` that you override in subclasses.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want are C++-like templates.

Comment: It sounds like he really wants is "duck typing".

Comment: ok reflection seems to be able to let me do everything I want. BTW, I thought I could overload fields as follows `junk xyz; xyz = new junkChild();`

Comment: Yucky. *Please* don't use reflection to solve this problem. It's an *ugly* solution. Your original wrapper method solution was *much* cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. It seems that this feature can be useful at time (duck typing). 
The method suggested by Matthew is fine except that during the time of writing `DoSomething`, I don't know in advance the types it will be using. `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` are two types, but in future, someone in our project may define a type `BigString` and the add should work as he has defined. The only requirement when implementing `BigString` is that the `add` function should take the same type and return the same type. Duck typing would have been very useful here.

Comment: Also, the programmer need not have to go into details of how `DoSomething` is implemented (i.e., if it uses `BigInteger`).. As far as he is concerned, `DoSomething` should be a blackbox.

Comment: @amit: Please select a correct answer to your question by clicking on the yellow checkbox next to the answer you consider best below. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do this - at least not at compile-time. The two `add` methods are effectively unrelated - they're not from an interface or anything like that.

You could do it with reflection (after adding properties for `a`, `b` and `c` or something similar - fields can't be "overridden" like this), but it wouldn't be terribly nice.

Comment: the most to-the-point answer. 

Out of curiosity, why can do this with `System.out.print`?
(We can define a `toString` method for any arbitrary class)

Comment: @Jus12: `toString()` inherits from `Object` which all classes ultimately inherit from. Any class can override `toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

The programming language feature you're asking about is called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and Java doesn't support it. You'll have to stick with your original wrapper method strategy.

Answer (score 2):

As has been said, Java doesn't do "duck typing" where the two types do not share a useful interface.  BigDecimal and BigInteger both extend Number, but the add() method is not part of that interface, so it doesn't help.

I think you need to make explicit what you are operating on in the method parameters of doSomething().  Then you can overrride doSomething() to operate on both types:

```
public BigDecimal doSomething(BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b) {
        return a.add( b );
}

public BigInteger doSomething(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(a);
    BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(b);
    BigDecimal z = doSomething(x, y);
    return z.toBigInteger();
}
```

The second method is simply a conversion method that then calls the real logic in the first method.

Comment: I have moved to Scala since then. In Scala these things are so easy `def foo[T <: {def add[T](a:T, b:T):Unit;val a:T}] (bar:T):T = ???`

Answer (score 1):

since Number (the closest ancestor of both classes doesn't have the add method), you can convert your BigInteger to BigDecimal first:

```
new BigDecimal(bi)
```